# Install web site in Ubuntu Server using Samba

Tags: samba

I've installed Ubuntu Server in VirtualBox running on Windows for someone to test a CMS. To make it easier managing the application, I decided to use Samba to access Apache's document root. What configuration do I need to make, and how do I access from Windows?

During installation I chose LAMP and Samba file server at the package selection step for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your document root is in /var/www/foo you need to setup a smb.conf with a section like this:

```
[global]
workgroup = WKG
netbios name = barserver
[foo]
path = /var/www/foo
```

With this settings you should be able to access the webspace from a windows computer in the LAN using \\barserver\foo

The accessing computer should be within the workgroup WKG.

Comment: What exactly is `netbios name`, and what does `[foo]` represent?

Comment: Netbios is for name resolving: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBIOS - it is the computer name in windows (barserver in this example). foo is the name of the shared ressource, [] is part of the syntax of the config file.

Comment: I don't know how shared filesystems work, how exactly does tge directory in `[foo]` show itself when I connect to the server?

Comment: you will find a computer with the name barserver in your workgroup and this will offer a shared folder called foo.

Comment: I see. And one last thing, there won't be any permission issues for `/var/www/*`, right?